# monitoring xinput in script

Tags: inotify, xinput

My laptop has a cracked touchscreen that the local Asus tech tells me can't be replaced, not even with a non-touch because they just don't make them anymore.

It is in all other respects a great laptop and works as well as ever with an external monitor but the crack on the screen sometimes generates random touch events that disrupt my session.

Disabling the screen with `xinput --disable 17` solves that problem, but some events unknown seem to re-enable it. I can set up a watch on that device like this:

```
 xinput --watch-props 17
 Device 'USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller':
 Device Enabled (177):  1
 ....
```

I want to parse out that 'Enabled' and respond with a `disable`.

So I want this to run as script, as a service perhaps, so that I can  re-disable the screen when it is re-enabled. However this script produces no output at all

```
 #!/bin/bash
 xinput --watch-props 17 | 
 while read event; do
    echo "$event"
 done
```

I have a number of `inotifywait` and `ip monitor` scripts that use this format and they all work as expected, but there's something wrong with this one.

Comment: the touch panel and the LCD are two separate devices ... it is possible that there are two separate connectors ... if there are two connectors, then you could unplug the touch panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `inotifywait` to actively re-disable the screen, you could tell the X server that the device is not needed.

You could do this by creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-no-touch.conf` with contents like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Disable a cracked touch screen"
    MatchProduct "USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller"
    # completely disregard the broken device
    Option "Ignore" "true"
    # alternative: just stop the device for being used as an active input device
    # Option "Floating" "true"
EndSection
```

I believe that the `Option "Ignore"...` line will suit your purposes better by completely removing the touchscreen from the list of input devices given by `xinput list`.

The alternative method using the `Option "Floating"...` line would allow the device to remain listed, but would designate the device as "not currently being used as part of the virtual core pointer/keyboard group", which effectively makes the device ignored by any X11 application that does not specifically request that particular input device.

Since I took the `MatchProduct` value from your `xinput --watch-props 17` output, it is probably correct, but if you need to tweak it, it might be helpful to look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see the exact identifier(s) used when the touchscreen controller is detected by the Xorg X11 server, and adjust the `Match...` clause accordingly. You can find more information on the various `Match...` keywords by using `man xorg.conf` on your system.